# How to show div of google maps after hidding it

Tags: jquery, css, google-maps

How to show `DIV` of `Google Maps` after I have set it's `Display:block`.

but after I showing it I get Google maps like in the following image, the image doesn't appear in whole DIV 
[image]

### edit

I have this code div that shows the map

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

css

---

```
#map{
width:500px;
height:500px;
diaplay:none;
}
```

jquery

---

```
$("#button").click(function(){
   $("#map").show();
});
```

Comment: Could you show us some code, to give us an idea of what you are actually trying to do?

The map is generated with a whole bunch of divs, and it looks as though you've only shown the first. You probably need to do .each(), or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common problem, it's an issue of not having a width or height properly set.
You have to tell it to redraw the map with something like this

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
map.setCenter(latlng);
```

although it would depend on the code and the api version you are using

Answer (score 1):

Initialize map on click, not on webpage start.

```
$("#button").click(function(){
   $("#map").show();
   // Start map here
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
diaplay:none;
```

should be

```
display:none;
```

but I'm not sure if that's causing your problem.